# DeletebyQuery replacement in NEST 2.0.4

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

My earlier version of NEST used to support the following code for DeleteByQuery

```
ESClient.DeleteByQuery<object>(q => q.Query(q1 => q1.QueryString(qs => qs.Query("*"))));
```

Now, that the nugetPackage of NEST elastic version has changed to 2.0.4, I am unable to work using the existing code. Could anyone please let me know what could be replacement for it. My Elastic Search is version 1.5.1

Thanks
cmrhema

Comment: NEST in version 2.x is not compatible with ES 1.x.

Comment: Thank you Rob for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEST 2.x is not compatible with Elasticsearch 1.x; there are breaking changes on the Elasticsearch side that are reflected as changes in NEST. [The NEST github repository shows the compatibility matrix](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net), which is essentially

- NEST 1.x is compatible with Elasticsearch 1.x
- NEST 2.x is compatible with Elasticsearch 2.x

and in prerelease, NEST 5.0.0-alpha1 is compatible with Elasticsearch 5.0.0-alpha1.

If you're using Elasticsearch 2.x, it is recommended to [use NEST 2.3.1, as it contains a fix for a memory leak that exists in prior NEST 2.x versions.](https://www.elastic.co/blog/nest-2-3-1-released)

DeleteByQuery is no longer part of Elasticsearch core in 2.x and [is available as a plugin.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/plugins-delete-by-query.html)